# Bash script to detect if I'm home or not through iPhone pings

Tags: bash

I'm working on this project to have music playing once I come into the appartment. I have a set of USB speakers connected to my routers USB port. I use OpenWRT to stream Radio through my router.
Now I want to try and use ping requests to a static IP that is assigned to my phone.
Idea:

Phone is home -> ping request positive -> bash activates MPD to play music
Phone is not at home -> ping request times out -> MPD stops playing

The problem with my script is that the Iphone disconnects from WLAN after a while. When I use my phone again, Wifi activates and music starts playing again, pretty annoying :)

Now I want to find a way to have the script only activate if it doesn't detect the phone for lets say 4 hours in a row. 
Here is my script:

```
ping 192.168.1.233 -c 1 -W 5 > /tmp/devicelist
status=$(grep -i -c '1 packets received' /tmp/devicelist)
prevStatus=$(cat /tmp/ishome)

if [ $status = $prevStatus ]; then
    echo "No change"
else
    if [ $status = "1" ]; then
        echo "Phone detected"
    mpc load bondi && mpc play 1
    else
        echo "Phone lost"
    mpc stop
    fi
fi

echo $status > /tmp/ishome
echo  $status | while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$(date) $line"; done >> /tmp/ishome.log
```

The last line was for debugging purpose. The script runs as a cron job every 5 mins
Can I use ishome.log which is a bunch of 0 as input?
Let's say I want the script to only execute if ishome.log has 10x0's?

Comment: You should also have the script check the time and not play music 9PM through 4PM...

Comment: great idea! I got inspired by this script on reddit: http://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/1yrudi/a_simple_bash_script_for_detecting_the_presence/  Unfortunately the date part does not work on OpenWRT

Answer (score 1):

You could for example count the number of zeros in the last 10 lines:

```
if [ "$(tail -n10 ishome.log | sort | uniq -c)" = "  10 0" ]; then echo 10 times 0; fi
```

Only if that condition is met and `$status` becomes 1 you'd play music.

Comment: Since I'm new in bash scripting I have trouble putting your suggestion into my script... could you help me with that?

Comment: Put the line under the "phone detected" output in your script and replace the `echo 10 times 0` part with whatever action you'd want it to do (e.g. your `mpc` commands).

When a phone is detected, it will then also check if the previous 10 times it checked no phone was detected before it plays music.

Comment: thanks! it's all ready to be tested! I'll post the finished script for reference once all the quirks are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, it's working now and I wanted to post my final script

```
NOW=$(date +"%s")
dayBegin=$(date --date="07:00" +"%s")
dayEnd=$(date --date="22:00" +"%s")
if [ ${NOW} -gt ${dayBegin} ] && [ ${NOW} -lt ${dayEnd} ]; then

ping 192.168.1.233 -c 1 -W 5 > /tmp/devicelist
   status=$(grep -i -c '1 packets received' /tmp/devicelist)
     if [ $status = "1" ]; then
         echo "Phone detected"
        if [ "$(tail -n60 /tmp/ishome.log | sort | uniq -c)" = "     60 0" ]; then
     mpc clear && mpc load all && mpc play 1

      fi
       else
           echo "Phone lost"
    mpc stop
      fi
fi
echo  $status | while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done >> /tmp/ishome.log
```

the cron tab:

```
* * * * * ~/musicphone.sh
* 2 * * * ~/logshorten.sh
```

So the script is being checked every minute which might seem like overkill but as soon as I come home, music starts playing and not 5 mins later. I also have a little script shortening the log every day to 500 lines

```
for file in /tmp/ishome.log; do
tail -500 "$file" > "$file.tmp"
mv -- "$file.tmp" "$file"
done
```

I'm sure there is smarter ways to go about this but this works well for me!